# Displaying attribute labels instead of attribute names in Yii2 audit trail extension output

Tags: yii2, audit-trail

I've installed an extension that displays database changes of curtain views. Audit_trail by bedezign.

It keeps all the changes in a table. There's a model field, a field field, etc.

"Model" field's values are like "app/model/Request".
"Field" field's values are field names.

I want to display field's labels instead of names.

I tried to implement it like this:

```
$m = $model->model;
return $m::getAttributeLabel($model->field);
```

I have the following error:

> Calling unknown method: yii\web\View::attributeLabels()

I guess this is because my $m variable is not being understood as a class, but as a simple string. Is there any way I can get around this?

Answer (score 1):

The method `getAttributeLabel()` is in the Model itself, and the input is a string.

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord.html#getAttributeLabel()-detail

> public string getAttributeLabel ( $attribute )

So try `$model->getAttributeLabel('fieldName')`

Comment: Sorry, can't understand how it differs from my code.

Comment: You're making `$m` from `$model`, so `$m` is a subset of your actual model object. And you call it with the static function-caller `::`